# Open download prompt with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, character-encoding, download, blob

I want to show a download prompt when user hits the Apps Script web app URL.

Here is my code which shows the download prompt. But the downloaded file is an invalid file. The zip file does not open.

I opened the invalid file with text editor and compared the same with original file's content. Although most characters match but some characters were missing.

```
function doGet(e) {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(DriveApp.getFileById("XXXXXXXXXXXX").getBlob().getDataAsString()).downloadAsFile("Example.zip");
}
```

Comment: Does this happen with all files used, or just that specific file? Could be an issue with the file.

Comment: No, the file looks good. Some issue with my code.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to view the file as PDF, you can use this [method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getAs(String)).
2. You can also try

   return ContentService
        .createTextOutput()
        .append(getFile(fileName))
        .downloadAsFile(fileName);

In getFile() method, you can get the actual file from drive.

Hope that helps!!